# Java: Anonymous Inner Class Instance Initializer Access to Outer Class Private Members

Tags: java, inner-classes

I have a situation where I can't change the main API of a set of classes, but I need to construct a new instance from archival data, including setting a large number of private fields.

My idea thus far was to create a static factory method that would produce my instance from the archival, like so:

Version 1:

```java
public class Item {
    private Long id;

    public static Item fromArchived(final ArchivedItem archived) {
        return new Item(){{
            this.id = archived.getId();
        }};
    }
}
```

IntelliJ IDEA gives me no red lines, I didn't have any idea there was an issue until I ran my maven build which yields:

```java
error: id has private access in Item
```

In contrast, this works:

Version 2:

```java
public class Item {
    private Long id;

    public static Item fromArchived(final ArchivedItem archived) {
        Item item = new Item(){{
//            this.id = archived.getId();
        }};

        item.id = archived.getId();

        return item;
    }
}
```

I've been reviewing my [core](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) [Java](http://books.google.com/books?id=Ww1B9O_yVGsC&pg=PA140&lpg=PA140&dq=instance%20initializer%20static%20context&source=bl&ots=Se7JcmT9hD&sig=YAY1a7400TDdTP32uuJqi7JrhBM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yzJNU9ypI4Hz8AGV6IGIBw&ved=0CDwQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=instance%20initializer%20static%20context&f=false) [knowledge](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html), and the only vague guess I have as to why Version 1 doesn't work is that the instance initializer (double brace initialization) somehow occurs in the static context, which doesn't really make sense either. Thoughts?

**EDIT**

I think the initial form of the question was vague. The answer I'm looking for is one which explains why I have visibility to the parent's private `id` field in the body of the static method but I lose visibility to it in the body of the instance initializer of the anonymous subclass inside that same static method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers have been accurate, but here's my take.

```
public class Item {
    private Long id;

    public static Item fromArchived(final ArchivedItem archived) {
        return new Item(){{
            this.id = archived.getId();
        }};
    }
}
```

Here the static method generates an anonymous class that extends Item.  Item$id will be hidden from this anonymous class.

The following snippet is equivalent to the previous, but as a named nested class that exposes a constructor method rather than a method that calls a constructor.

```
public class Item {
    private Long id;

    class FromArchived extends Item {
        public FromArchived(final ArchivedItem archived) {
            this.id = archived.getId();
        }
    }
}
```

The visibility modifiers are enforced consistently whether the access is from a named, nested or anonymous class.

Finally, this following snippet should work as while inside a class, you have full access to all the private fields & methods of that class.

```
public class Item {
    private Long id;

    public static Item fromArchived(final ArchivedItem archived) {
        Item item = new Item();
        item.id = archived.getId();
        return item;
    }
}
```

This is true whether you're in a constructor, method or static method.

Answer (score 1):

you have been creating anonymous inner class that extends the `Item` class.`private` variables are accessible from within the same class where those declared.So you are not allowed to access `Item` class private variables in `anonymous` inner class

Comment: I see. I tried without the this and that complained that id can't be accessed in a static context.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, `this` refers to anonymous (inner) `Item`, not the outer, that's why you get error message.

Comment: I'm intentionally referring the the inner's `id` because there is no outer `id` in the static context. I'm trying to factory create an instance, and I clearly have visibility into the instance's private fields (a la Version 2 above), but my visibility is restricted in the case of instance initializers?

Answer (score 1):

With the construct below you create `Item` subclass with instance initialization block inside.

```
return new Item() { // equivalent to: class AnonymousItem extends Item
    {
        this.id = archived.getId();
    }
};
```

Subclasses do not have access to private fields of parent classes, so compiler generates error for you.

Comment: I realize that in normal situations that subclasses don't have access to parent's private fields, but why wouldn't an inner class have that access?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing `this.id = ...` you may write `((Item) this).id = ...` or `super.id = ...`.